# Is there a way to pass a variable to an aspx file via the url?

Tags: android, asp.net

I am trying to write a little Android app for my daughter.  The goal is to scan a book's bar code and pass the ISBN number to this website:  http://www.arbookfind.com/default.aspx .  The result will show if the book is part of the Accelerated Reader program and how many points the book is worth.  I am trying to automate the part where the ISBN would need to be entered into the search field.

For simplicity's sake, and because I'm not a programmer, I am using MIT's App Inventor 2.  I can now scan and get the ISBN but I will need to know how to format a URL to the website that will allow me to pass the ISBN to it's search page.

Is it possible to send a variable via the URL similar to index.php?myvar=testing&someothervar=somethingelse  ?  I've tried but perhaps I am not using the correct variable name or format for aspx.  Is there an easy way to see what the variable name is in the aspx displayed page in my browser?

*EDIT* To clarify, I am not trying to scrape data and avoid showing ads from the site I am using to generate the results.  I am wanting to pass the ISBN number to the page and have it search and display the resulting page in the phone's browser.  I am also fine with a method that would populate the search field and the user would have to hit the search button if that can be accomplished easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend abandoning this route, as it is highly unlikely that the owners of this website will want you passing a query string to their site anyway, but rather they will most likely point you to an Application Programming Interface (API) that they provide, so that your program can connect to this service (free or paid, depending upon the company) and then you can request the book's details by providing the ISBN in the request.

There is no discovery mechanism for an `.aspx` page like there is for a web service to find out the names of things to pass. Even if you figure out what the name of the query string is that you could pass in for ISBN, you run the risk of the implementation being changed and your "application breaking". While this is also true of web service APIs, since APIs are the route the website providers want you to use, as opposed to screenscraping, then they generally inform their users of breaking changes or newer versions of the API via documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see that page does not accept URL-variables for their search field the way google.com and other does. The page is generated through some sort of content management system (CMS) and it relies heavily on javascript to make things work. I tried doing a normal search there, and you have two issues you need to wriggle around.

First, the page redirects you to a page where you select if your a student, parent etc. It seems that it relies on some session cookie to remember the setting, but it times out pretty fast.

Second, the form uses javascript to trigger the search, and it appears to be done using AJAX, a method of using javascript to trigger actions on the server and displaying the results, without actually loading the page again. You might be able to get a hold of the javascript code used and re-engineer it for your purposes, and call that using HTTP POST and/or GET from your app, but it is a tricky path, and quite possibly not allowed by the company since you will be loading data from their site, without presenting their advertisements and thus be costing them money.